# AltGr key released when rapidly pressing other keys

Tags: keyboard, compose-key

I have a Norwegian Lenovo USB keyboard.

When I hold <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and press <kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd> rapidly, it produces `“bvbv` instead of `“”“”“”`. I get the latter expected result when pressing <kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd> slowly. Never letting go of <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

`xev` shows that the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key is released when pressing <kbd>b</kbd> for the first time when doing this rapidly. ([Output](http://hastebin.com/gomuroyasa.sm).)

Any idea what could be causing this?

Updated Debian Jessie with GNOME desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Aeyoun,

```
http://www.xfree86.org/4.0/xmodmap.1.html
```

Have you attempted to correct this by applying an xmodmap to your X11 session?

This will intercept the keys affected, and apply the output you require.

```
xmodmap -pke > crud
```

will display your Key-Map to Key-Code bindings.

Determine the Key-Map Identity which are producing incorrect Key-Code Identity bindings.

When you understand the identity of what you are inputting (Key-Map Identity) to Key-Code Bindings, you will be able to set the Key-Map to Key-Code binding appropriately and store it in your X11 session.

You need to modify your .Xinitrc to run these xmodmap commands.

I've personally used xmodmap to disable input keys on "padlocked" systems. You can reconfigure your entire keyboard using this knowledge.

This is the fix. Trust me. Xmodmap will solve it.